# Spring MVC - GWT integration Using Spring STS

Tags: eclipse, gwt, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have a spring mvc-based application using spring STS.

I want to integrate it with GWT , so I can build nice UI.

I saw [this](http://technophiliac.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/giving-gwt-a-spring-in-its-step/).

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040644/experiences-with-integrating-spring-3-mvc-with-gwt) thread

But they weren't using spring sts, and the post is almost 5 years old.

My question is:

1. Should I stay in my spring mvc project, or should I open a GWT project?
2. In case I can stay with my spring mvc project, what are the steps I need to do, to perform a connection between my GWT client and my spring Service tier?

Any code example or tutorials will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate GWT with Spring MVC using Spring MVC REST and GWT JavaScriptObjects.

Take a look at the following GitHub [code](https://github.com/doanduyhai/StockWatcherJSON).

For a more "complicated" example of using JavaScriptObject, look [here](http://bluediamondsfx.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/nesting-javascriptobjects-in-javascript-overlay-types-in-gwt/).